# How do i make a button that will place info in a different worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a time tracker that will be used to track associates time on any given task. I want to set it up so that the buttons to start and stop time are on the first sheet and the actual data being generated is on the next sheet. The code I have works, but it is just putting the data in the same sheet as the button. Here is what I have:

```
Sub StartBooking()

Dim lr As Long
lr = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("a" & lr + 1).Formula = "=now()"
Range("b" & lr + 1) = "Booking"
Range("c" & lr + 1) = "Start"
Range("a" & lr + 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("d" & lr + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats 

End Sub
```

I know that this is extremely simple so let me add a disclaimer. Any knowledge of excel vba I have is completely self taught. I am new to coding (this is my first project) and find it very interesting, but I'm in way over my head. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default data gets put on the `ActiveSheet`. You need to explicitly call out to the worksheet that you want to want to put the data onto. You can do this by calling the specific name of the sheet or the indexed position of the sheet. The indexed position is where the sheet is currently with respect to the other sheets.

```
Sub StartBooking()

    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets(2).Range("a" & lr + 1).Formula = "=now()"
    Sheets(2).Range("b" & lr + 1) = "Booking"
    Sheets(2).Range("c" & lr + 1) = "Start"
    Sheets(2).Range("a" & lr + 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(2).Range("d" & lr + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats 

End Sub
```

You could also call out to the sheet by name with something like `Sheets("DataSheet")`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It works for the first three but when it comes to copying the time stamp to paste its value it gives me a 400 error.

Comment: I just needed to get rid of the select and selection part so the final code for the copy paste is just       sheets(2).range("a" & lr + 1).copy and the same to paste the value. Thanks again!